# Is $T : \mathbb{C} \rightarrow \mathbb{C}: a + bi \mapsto \overline{a + bi} = a - bi$ a linear image?

Tags: linear-algebra, complex-numbers, vector-spaces, linear-transformations

So a question in my handbook for linear algebra is the following; Is the linear map T
$$T :\mathbb{C} \rightarrow \mathbb{C}: a + bi \mapsto \overline{a + bi} = a - bi$$

an linear image if:

- $\mathbb{C}$ is interpreted as a real vector space
- $\mathbb{C}$ is interpreted as a complex vector space

I know how I would solve the question itself (I would check the axiom of linear image: if $L: V \rightarrow W$ is a linear map then $L(\lambda_1v_1 + \lambda_2v_2) = \lambda_1L(v_1) + \lambda_2L(v_2)$) but I'm stuck at what they mean with the interpretation.

Comment: If $\mathbb{C}$ is treated as a real-vector space, then it is 2 dimensional, in fact, isomorphic to $\mathbb{R}$.

Comment: How would I see that it is 2 dimensional? Isomorphism comes in a later chapter in the book so is there any way to solve this without it as well?

Comment: It is not clear to me what is meant with "linear image" as opposed to "linear map". Usually one fixes a field $K$ up front and assumes that "vector space" means $K$-vector space and "linear map" means $K$-linear map. And between $K$-vector spaces, a "linear map" would implicitly be taken to mean $K$-linear map. But when some other field is at play, as here $\Bbb R$ when the $V$ is naturally a complex vector space, then one can either say explicitly "$\Bbb R$-linear map $V\to V$", or more implicitly "linear map $V\to V$ where $V$ is viewed as real vector space"; it means the same.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hint.

- $T$ is a $\mathbb{R}$-linear map.
- $T$ is not a $\mathbb{C}$-linear map.

---

Notes.

- $\mathbb{C}$ is one-dimensional vector space over the filed $\mathbb{C}$   where $\alpha=(1)$ is a basis.
- $\mathbb{C}$ is two-dimensional vector space over the filed
  $\mathbb{R}$ where $\beta=(1,i)$ is an (ordered) basis.

When you talk about "linear maps", you need to know the underlying vector spaces (over what *field*). The field determines what scalar $\lambda$ you need to check for
$$
T(\lambda_1v_1+\lambda_2v_2)=\lambda_1T(v_1)+\lambda_2T(v_2)\tag{1}
$$

If $T$ is $\mathbb{C}$-linear, it means that (1) is true
for all ***complex** numbers* $\lambda_1$ and $\lambda_2$.

If $T$ is $\mathbb{R}$-linear, it means that (1) is true
for all ***real** numbers* $\lambda_1$ and $\lambda_2$.

In your example, try to see what is $T(iz)$.

Comment: So they basically ask to interpret $\mathbb{C}$ as a vectorspace $(\mathbb{R}, \mathbb{C}, +)$ and $(\mathbb{C}, \mathbb{C}, +)$?

Comment: @MatthiasK. if you mean $(F,V,+,\cdot)$ where $F$ is the underlying field and $V$ is the vector space, then yes.

Comment: I have never seen fields (it is mentioned in the book but there isn't any theory about it). We only see vector spaces, which are noted the way I said in the previous comment

Comment: @MatthiasK. you may not have seen "fields", but you should have seen in what set the scalar $\lambda_1$ and $\lambda_2$ belong to, in the definition of "linear map". That's the underlying "field" for the vector space.

Comment: So here they just mean that I must use the field of real numbers (resp. complex numbers)?

Comment: @MatthiasK. Yes, that's from the definition of [linear maps](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linear_map#Definition_and_first_consequences).

Comment: Ok thanks! That's good to know!

Answer (score 5):

Assuming that you meant “linear map”, $T$ is a linear map if you see $\Bbb C$ as a real vector space, since, if $z,w\in\Bbb C$ and $\alpha,beta\in\Bbb R$, we have\begin{align}T(\alpha z+\beta w)&=\overline{\alpha z+\beta w}\\&=\alpha\overline z+\beta\overline w\text{ (because $\alpha,\beta\in\Bbb R$)}\\&=\alpha T(z)+\beta T(w).\end{align}

But $T$ is *not* a linear map if you see $\Bbb C$ as a complex vector space, because for instance, $T(i\times i)\ne i\times T(i).$

Comment: Yes I do mean linear map, I didn't know what it was in English. Edited my post!